# Can UA Lore Mastery's Spell Secrets feature change the damage type of a spell that does not deal damage immediately?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, unearthed-arcana, damage-types

For UA Lore Mastery, Spell Secrets states the following:

> At 2nd level, when you cast a spell with a spell slot and the spell **deals acid, cold, fire, force, lightning, necrotic, radiant, or thunder damage,** you can **substitute** that damage type with one other type from that list (you can change only one damage type per casting of a spell). You replace one energy type for another by altering the spell's formula as you cast it.

This applies easily enough for instant-damage spells. However, the wording does not specify that the damage must be dealt immediately in order to be eligible for the change. Would I then be able to change the damage type of, say, *holy weapon* from radiant to another type? Or substitute the necrotic damage of a *symbol* spell for cold?

Note: I am aware that Lore Mastery is playtest material.

Answer (score 3):

### There are no hidden rules

1. Is it a spell?
2. Does it do acid, cold, fire, force, lightning, necrotic, radiant, or thunder damage?

If the answer to both is yes then you can use Spell Mastery.